# Extracting File Extensions from AppleScript Paths

Tags: directory, applescript, filenames, filepath, file-extension

I'm writing an Apple Script that ultimately will mark commercials for all iTunes exports from EyeTV. But I'm running into a simple problem with AppleScript paths, which the EyeTV app returns as recording locations. Here's the context:

```
set recordingID to 370404006
set myid to recordingID as integer
tell application "EyeTV"
    set eyetvr_file to get the location of recording id myid as alias
end tell
return eyetvr_file
```

> alias "Macintosh HD2:Documents:EyeTV Archive:South Park.eyetv:000000001613eaa6.eyetvr"

Now I need to extract the containing path and the file prefix 000000001613eaa6 (using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278704/applescript-get-filenames-in-folder-without-extension)) so I can look for the corresponding commercial markings in the file 000000001613eaa6.edl. Here's the hiccup:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set eyetv_path to container of eyetvr_file
    set root_name to name of eyetvr_file
    set fext to name extension of eyetvr_file
end tell
```

The results are,

> eyetv_path: document file "South Park.eyetv" of folder "EyeTV Archive" of folder "Documents" of disk "Macintosh HD2" of application "Finder"
>
> root_name: "000000001613eaa6.eyetvr"
>
> fext: ""

fext should be ".eyetvr", not the empty string. How do I correctly extract ".eyetvr" from either eyetvr_file or root_name? I've tried a bunch of hack like

```
set fext to name extension of (eyetvr_file as document)
```

But this gives error like,

> error "Can’t make alias \"Macintosh HD2:Documents:EyeTV Archive:South Park.eyetv:000000001613eaa6.eyetvr\" into type document." number -1700 from alias "Macintosh HD2:Documents:EyeTV Archive:South Park.eyetv:000000001613eaa6.eyetvr" to document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finder doesn't recognize all filename extensions. You could just use text item delimiters to remove the last part though.

```
do shell script "touch /tmp/some.file.eyetvr"
set text item delimiters to "."
tell application "Finder"
    set n to name of file (POSIX file "/tmp/some.file.eyetvr")
    if n contains "." then set n to (text items 1 thru -2 of n) as text
    n -- some.file
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly with the edits below, and provides a better solution  that the one I linked to. This code gave me an error unless I specified "AppleScript's text item delimiters", and I also saved the previous settings for use in a larger code block: "set delims to AppleScript's text item delims <br> set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "." <br> &hellip; set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delims"

Answer (score 1):

Mini-comments apparently do not allow posting code, so here are my edits to Lauri Ranta's nice solution:

```
do shell script "touch /tmp/some.file.eyetvr"
set delims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
tell application "Finder"
    set n to name of file (POSIX file "/tmp/some.file.eyetvr")
    if n contains "." then set n to (text items 1 thru -2 of n) as text
    n -- some.file
end tell
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delims
```

I'll post a link to the EyeTV-commercial-marking-script-for-iOS when I've finished that project.

Comment: Here's a link to the resulting AppleScript, ExportDone.scpt: https://code.google.com/p/etv-comskip/downloads/detail?name=ETVComskip_h264_HD_mods-1.0rc1.zip&can=2&q=